# Creating a qcow2 image from *inside* a running VPS?

Tags: linux, backup, vmware, qemu, vps

Ideally, I'd like to create a qcow2 image of a VPS, from *inside* a running instance of that VPS. I'm not sure if this is possible, but I don't think so.

The problem is that my VPS provider will let me create backup images, but there's no way to export that image (it can only be used to restore a VPS to a previous state, or to create new VPS instances). They're running VMware, if it's relevant. They do have a "backup solution", which involves installing (and paying monthly for) Acronis, but I'm not sure how this works or what it actually gives me.

Do I have any other options for 'hot' backups, or am I just stuck with trying to rsync the entire (Ubuntu 22.04) server (minus pseudo/virtual files??) to my own local storage, and hoping for the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's technically possible, but the simplest method (reading from /dev/sda) won't be a proper "frozen in time" dump, it'll be a possibly inconsistent filesystem that would need repairs.

It would help if your next server instance had LVM, which supports atomic snapshots that can be safely transferred (and then destroyed) while the server continues to run. With LVM snapshots, instead of imaging /dev/sda you will be able to image /dev/mapper/something which *is* frozen in time.

Even better would be to use a filesystem that has file-level snapshots built in (e.g. Btrfs or ZFS, or perhaps XFS in the near future), as both Btrfs and ZFS already have snapshot-based backup tools such as `zfs send`.

But if snapshots are not available – just rsync the entire system, then immediately rsync it *again.* The 2nd run will be minimal and catch everything that changed during the 1st run; you can loop a few more times until there are no more changes.

Also, even without snapshots, some filesystems can be *frozen* by running `fsfreeze` – then all write calls are paused so you can semi-safely rsync all files as they will not change until a `fsfreeze -u` is run. (Be careful as this may also cause *new login attempts* to hang if the SSH service tries to write to log files.)

Keep in mind that many database services require specific tools to make a "hot" backup (e.g. LMDB may need mdb_copy), but this applies equally to VPS-level snapshots as it does to rsync or LVM, so nothing new there.

Note: Instead of manually excluding /dev, /proc, etc. consider that all of them are *separate filesystems* and would be automatically excluded by using `--one-file-system`.

Comment: Thanks - the image is on LVM, so I'll give that a go.